# Convert Rows to column in sql server 2008 without pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to convert my second and third columns into rows by doing grouping on first column. below is my current data:

```
vendor       technology          version
microsoft    sql server          2008
microsoft    sql server          2012
microsoft    windows             xp
microsoft    .NET Framework      1.1 SP1
oracle       Hyperion Essbase    11
Adobe        Adobe Acrobat       4
Adobe        Adobe Acrobat       7
```

I want the result for one vendor in 1 row only like below:

```
Vendor     technology-version technology-version   technology-version  technology-version
microsoft  sql server-2008    sql server-2012      windows-XP        .NET Framework-1.1 SP1
oracle     Hyperion Essbase-11
Adobe      Adobe Acrobat-4    Adobe Acrobat-7
```

It seems i don't have access to pivot as i get below error message:

> Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: Post the query that's throwing an error.

Comment: I assume your database is running in "80" (SQL Server 2000) compatibility mode. Is there a specific reason for that? If not: **update** the compatibility level (`ALTER DATABASE (yourDatabaseName) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100`) and your query should work just fine!

Comment: @marc_s: ...even though we cannot see it right now? :)